# Building a text extractor to extract particular type of text from unstructured text data

Tags: machine-learning, python, data-mining, nlp, nltk

I have a lot of data and manually extracted annotations for the text. I was looking for any advice to automate the annotation extraction up to a good level of accuracy. Any advice is welcome.

Comment: Read about _information extraction_ and [Markov logic networks](http://homes.cs.washington.edu/~pedrod/803/) ([python implementation](http://www.pracmln.org))

Comment: It would help if you could provide an example.

Comment: I have a lot of medical data and one particular symptom manually extracted from all of them. I want to automate this process.

Answer (score 0):

There is a spectrum of methods. On one end is the tried n' true method of performing pattern matching with rules. Write a series of regular expressions (i.e., regex). On the other end is the newer methods of weak supervision, a system that learns over time to get better. [Snorkel](http://hazyresearch.github.io/snorkel/) one of implementation of weak supervision. [Here are some snorkel demos](https://github.com/snorkel-team/snorkel-tutorials).